# jQuery How to change class for each table data row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table, with data, and i need for **td:eq(4)** change class, and box for baghround.

I have this code:

```
 $('tr').each(function () {
        var rowCol = $(this);
        rowCol.find('td:eq(4)').each(function () {
            var rowValue = parseFloat($(this).text());
            console.log(rowValue === 0)
            if (rowValue > 1) {
                $('.defects').addClass('def').removeClass('defects');
            } else {
                $('.def').addClass('defects').removeClass('def');
            }
        });
    });


.defects {
    background: #e74c3c;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

And if at this td i have value more then 1, i add bg red box.

But nox, something went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your html, I can only guess about how it looks based on your code, but try this:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
  var rowCol = $(this);
  rowCol.find('td:eq(4)').each(function() {
    var mytd = $(this);
    var rowValue = parseFloat($(this).text());
    console.log(rowValue === 0)
    if (rowValue > 1) {
      mytd.addClass('def').removeClass('defects');
    } else {
      mytd.addClass('defects').removeClass('def');
    }
  });
});
```

first of, I'm assigning your `td:eq(4)` to a variable `var mytd = $(this);`.

 then I'm replacing `$('.defects')` with `mytd`

**Code**

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
  var rowCol = $(this);
  rowCol.find('td:eq(4)').each(function() {
    var mytd = $(this);
    var rowValue = parseFloat($(this).text());
    console.log(rowValue === 0)
    if (rowValue > 1) {
      mytd.addClass('def').removeClass('defects');
    } else {
      mytd.addClass('defects').removeClass('def');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.defects {
  background: #e74c3c;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can run the demo above and see the result.